# How to get a value in parentheses using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like this one:

```
String s = "BRACKET (center)";
```

The strings always contain `"BRACKET ()"` but what is in the parentheses changes. How can I capture that changing value reliably?

Here is what I have tried but it does not seem to do the trick:

```
String newLine = s.replaceAll("^BRACKET\\s\\(\\)", "");
System.out.println(newLine);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
String newLine = s.replaceAll("^BRACKET\\s\\((.*)\\)", "$1");
```

Note the extra `(.*)`, this will match whatever string is inside the parenthesis. Then the `$1` will reference what was matched before (each pair of parenthesis forms a group that you can reference later; as there's only one pair, you reference it as `$1`)